# Estou com Erro nas viewModel ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, mvc

Pelo que procurei, usamos viewmodel para depois acedermos na view a vários model, o meu problema é que estou com um erro que nao me permite aceder aos Model. E em todo o lado que pesquiso nao consigo perceber onde estou a falhar.
ViewModel:

```
 public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; } = new List<Category>();
    public List<Ad> Ads { get; set; } = new List<Ad>();
}
```

Controller:

```
public class ViewModelController : Controller
{
    private LivrinhosContext db = new LivrinhosContext();
    // GET: ViewModel
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewModel mymodel = new ViewModel();

        mymodel.Categories = db.Categories.ToList(); //Get all categories
        mymodel.Ads = db.Ads.Take(1).OrderByDescending(x => x.BookID).ToList(); //get last ad 

        return View(mymodel);
    }
}
```

A view:

```
    @model IEnumerable<LivrinhosMVC.DAL.ViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin:2em 0">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            @Html.Label("Categorias")
            <table class="table-condensed">
                @foreach (var category in Model.Categories) {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.ActionLink(category.Name, "../Category/Books", new { id = category.ID }, null)</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8" style="display:inline">
            @Html.TextBox("BookTitle", null, new { placeholder = "Título...", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.DropDownList("Cities", "Portugal")
            @Html.ActionLink("Pesquisar", "Books", null, null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            @foreach (var ad in Model.Ads)
            {
                <div class="col-sm-3">


                    @Html.Label(ad.Title)
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Você está retornando uma ViewModel para uma view que espera IEnumerable<ViewModel>.

Comment: Qual o erro apresentado?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está retornando uma `ViewModel` para sua view que na verdade espera receber um `IEnumerable<ViewModel>`.

Reveja a `model` da sua `view`. O correto para ela receber o valor retornado na `ViewModelController` é:

```
@model LivrinhosMVC.DAL.ViewModel
```

Caso contrário você precisa rever sua ViewModel e a sua Controller para fazer um envio do tipo `IEnumerable<ViewModel>`.

Answer (score 0):

Por que não cria a `viewModel` com objeto inteiro de **Category** e **Ad**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Category Categories  { get; set; }
    public Ad Ads  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta faz sentido, mas fazendo isso ele precisa alterar também a controller.